# How to use third-party Styles with React and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, reactgo

tried dozens of workarounds now and I am really not able to get it to work.

My Setup is a clean "reactGo"-App ( https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo ) which has Webpack2 included.

Now i am trying to bring react-calendar-timeline ( https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline ) to life.

Right after doing this, the first error you got is:

> D:\Users\Documents\sandbox\reactGo\node_modules\react-calendar-timeline\modules\lib\Timeline.css:1
>
> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .react-calendar-timeline * { SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

In the reactGo-Repository you can see the full Webpack configuration. As I told, I tried several workarounds, but everything returns in other error-messages.

If I exclude the required css in the calendar-timeline.js directly and import it in my own jsx file, it works of course. But this is a really ugly workaround and I want to collaborate with other developers. Can't told them we have to exlude a require out of an external module.

Can you told me what is going wrong here? I'm out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/issues/838

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a great workaround for static extensions like bootstrap. But i need to get out of this error which comes from the css import from calendar-timeline itself. So it is only solvable by fixing the webpack configuration.